Confidence intervals with scipy
I have an array of shape (n, timesteps), where n is the number of trials and timesteps is the length of each trial. Each value of this array denotes a stochastic measurement.
I would like to implement a generic function that computes a confidence interval for a given statistic (mean, median, ...) assuming 1) the underlying distribution is normal, 2) is Student's.
Something like
def normal_ci(
    data: np.array,
    axis: int = 0,
    statistic: Callable = np.mean,
    confidence: float = 0.95
):

and a similar function student_ci().
My problem is that, by default, scipy functions compute intervals for the mean, am I right? Like in this answer.

This is on Stack Overflow, so the computational answer is to use the bootstrap.
from typing import Callable
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng(84354894298246)

def normal_ci(
    data: np.array,
    axis: int = 0,
    statistic: Callable = np.mean,
    confidence: float = 0.95
):
    res = stats.bootstrap((data,), statistic, axis=axis,
                          confidence_level=confidence)
    return tuple(res.confidence_interval)

# generate 1000 samples, each of length 100
data = rng.standard_normal(size=(1000, 100))

# compute the confidence interval for each
low, high = normal_ci(data, axis=-1)

# the confidence interval contains the population value
# of the statistic in 95% of cases
np.mean((low < 0) & (0 < high))  # 0.953

Since you know the families from which your data are drawn, you could look into the parametric bootstrap.
def normal_ci(
    data: np.array,
    axis: int = 0,
    statistic: Callable = np.mean,
    confidence: float = 0.95
):
    # fit a normal distribution to the data
    mean = np.mean(data, axis=axis)
    std = np.std(data, ddof=1, axis=axis)

    # resample data from the fitted normal distribution
    n_resamples = 999
    m = data.shape[axis]  # assuming axis is an integer
    resample = rng.normal(loc=mean, scale=std, size=(m, n_resamples) + mean.shape)

    # compute the statistic for each of the resamples to estimate
    # the distribution
    statistic_distribution = statistic(resample, axis=0)

    # Generate the confidence interval
    # percentile bootstrap (very crude)
    alpha = 1 - confidence
    low, high = np.quantile(statistic_distribution, [alpha/2, 1-alpha/2], axis=0)
    return low, high

low, high = normal_ci(data, axis=-1)
np.mean((low < 0) & (0 < high))  # 0.954

SciPy's bootstrap function uses the BCa method by default, which is reasonably sophisticated; this parametric bootstrap is what I could write in a few minutes. So for parametric bootstrap, you really should research what other libraries are out there.
If you're not happy with the bootstrap, you'd need to do some research: for each of the statistics and population families you're interested in, you need to know the distribution of the statistic of a sample drawn from your population. For a sample from a normal distribution, the sample mean is t-distributed, the variance is chi-squared distributed, etc... and that is not a question for Stack Overflow.

Thanks, I have already implemented bootstrapping but I didn't think about the parametric version. Thanks! I tried yours but when I pass statistic = np.median to your parametric implementation, I get an interval that is almost the same to the mean's. This does not happen if I do non-parametric bootstrapping.

Both are approximate and stochastic. I explained that the second was a crude sketch of parametric bootstrapping. So yeah, they may give different results. Check whether the coverage seems to be about right over many trials; that is the true test.
Thanks are appreciated, but please remember Stack Overflow's recommendations on how to say it: "Comments are not recommended for any of the following... Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, upvote it and pay it forward;" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Sure, I always upvote and accept an answer if it's right :) Sometime I wait a bit because when I do and ask for something with a comment, the person who answered just ignores my comments. Thanks again for replying!
